# Add css rule to parent only if child does not have a particular attribute without using jquery

Tags: css, css-selectors, parent-child, parent-selector

I want to add some css rule to parent if their is no child with particular attribute without using jquery.

Comment: Nothing worked for me from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector.Can anyone help me out?